# Find minimum no. of fountains needed

Tags: arrays

There is a linear garden from 1 to n. At each point there is a fountain. Given array a[n]tells info about fountain such that its range is max(i-a[i],1) to the left of fountain to min(i+a[i],n) to the right of fountain. Find minimum no. of fountains needed to be activated so that whole garden is covered.
 e.g.if n=3 and a={1,2,1} then second fountain has range 1 to 3. So only 1 fountain needed.          Here fountain at 1 has range of 1 to 2,
      fountain at 2 has range of 1 to 3 and fountain at 3 has range of 2 to 3
So only fountain 2 is enough to be activated to cover the whole garden.

Comment: What is your question?  Please refer to $`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask`$ in order to get help with code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @ravenspoint What is the question?

Comment: Getting homework done ?

Comment: Its actually an interview question.

Answer (score 7):

Traverse through all the fountains and construct array jumps:

jumps[i] = {max range of all the fountains having their range's left boundary at i}

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
l = max(1, i - arr[i-1])
r = min(n, i + arr[i-1])
jumps[l] = max(jumps[l], r - l);
}
```

Then apply Jump Game II (https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game-ii/) on jumps array.
This takes O(n) time

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-jumps-reach-endset-2on-solution/

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for this solution off O(n) time and O(n) space.

Create interval array to store the right most range which can be covered from the current index.

```
public int findMinActivatedFountain(int[] arr, int n) {
        int[] interval = new int[n];
        int count = 1;

        // At each index we'll store the max right possible from this index.
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            int left = Math.max(i - arr[i - 1], 1);
            int right = Math.min(i + arr[i - 1], n);

            interval[left - 1] = right;
        }

        int right = interval[0];
        int currMax = right;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            currMax = Math.max(currMax, interval[i]);

            // If the last fountain can cover only this point, then update with next fountain.
            if (i == right) {
                count++;
                right = currMax;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't cover all corner cases

Comment: Working for me...Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Ravi's answer is correct, but there's a little bug in that

```
// At each index we'll store the max right possible from this index.
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int left = Math.max(i - arr[i - 1], 1);
        int right = Math.min(i + arr[i - 1], n);

        interval[left - 1] = right;
    }
```

Here it should be `interval[left-1] = max(interval[left-1],right)`,
We should store the max of all ranges with that point being the starting point. Rest all is correct.

Answer (score 0):

- Assign most powerful fountain so that it covers 1 to 2 * range -1
- Remove assigned fountain and 1 to 2 * range - 1 from garden
- recurse

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually the range is max(i-a[i],1) to left of fountain and min(i+a[i],n) to right of the fountain. Can you please give me a dp solution.

Comment: What is a "dp solution"?

Comment: solution by using dynamic programming

Comment: Why would you want such a complicated thing.  Straightforward recursion will give the answer in a few lines of code.  With a few more lines, you could also use a for loop ( recursion scares some )

Answer (score 0):

- Time complexity- O(n)
- store the lower and upper limits of the range in an array (fountainArray below)
- take a stack, to select all the fountains you will need. Initially stack is empty.

```
    rightLimit =0; 
    leftLimit = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(rightLimit> fountainArray[i].rightLimit){
            if(leftLimit<= fountainArray[i].leftLimit){
                fountainStack.pop();
                //similarly check left limit of the new fountain on top
                //keep popping elements till fountainArray[i].leftLimit is > leftLimit of 
                //fountain on top of stack
            }
            fountainStack.push(fountainArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return fountainStack.length();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int find(int arr[], int n){
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
   int l = max(1, i - arr[i-1])
   int r = min(n, i + arr[i-1])
  jumps[l] = max(jumps[l], r - l);
}
int longest = jump(jumps);
if(arr.lenght ==  longest){
 return 0;    
}else{
  return arr.length-longest-1;
}
}


// get the minimum jump to reach
public static int jump(int[] A) {
int sc = 0;
int e = 0;
int max = 0;
for(int i=0; i<A.length-1; i++) {
    max = Math.max(max, i+A[i]);
    if( i == e ) {
        sc++;
        e = max;
    } 
}
return sc;
}
```